# Loop not properly modifying array elements

Tags: java, arrays

The loop causing issues is the second for loop.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class StudentScores {
   public static void main (String [] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      final int NUM_POINTS = 4;
      int[] dataPoints = new int[NUM_POINTS];
      int controlValue;
      int i;

      controlValue = scnr.nextInt();

      for (i = 0; i < dataPoints.length; ++i) {
         dataPoints[i] = scnr.nextInt();
      }

      for (i = 0; dataPoints[i] < controlValue; ++i) {
         dataPoints[i] = dataPoints[i] * 2;
      }

      for (i = 0; i < dataPoints.length; ++i) {
         System.out.print(dataPoints[i] + " ");
      }
      System.out.println();
   }
}
```

Currently when i run the test, this is what pops up.

Testing with inputs: `10 2 12 9 20`

Output differs.

Your output

```
4 12 9 20
```

Expected output

```
4 12 18 20
```

the first number in the list of inputs is the maximum number it should multiply by 2. Since 20 is > 10, it is not multiplied. However 9 should be multiplying to 18, but it is not. If anyone could give some insight into anything i might be doing wrong when forming this loop, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: your second for loop is exiting because of your condition, you should instead iterate through the dataPoints in full and make the check within the loop before multiplying.

Comment: Andrew, if you're learning to program (you appear to be using one of the online programming challenge sites), the very best thing to learn is how to use a debugger to step through code that isn't doing what you want/expect it to. With a debugger, you will see what the code _does_, not what you think it does (in this case, exiting the loop when it sees the `12` that is not less than `10`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second for loop is exiting because of the condition and the order of your input data, and will stop when a control value is reached. For example, if you instead had an input of `10 1 2 3 4`, you would get the results you expect (ie. `2 4 6 8`), but your for loop is exiting when the condition `dataPoints[i] < controlValue` is reached (in your case at `12`).

Instead you should loop through the entire `dataPoints` array, as you do in your 3rd loop, and check the `controlValue` before doubling the values.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class StudentScores {
   public static void main (String [] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      final int NUM_POINTS = 4;
      int[] dataPoints = new int[NUM_POINTS];
      int controlValue;
      int i;

      controlValue = scnr.nextInt();

      for (i = 0; i < dataPoints.length; ++i) {
         dataPoints[i] = scnr.nextInt();
      }

      for (i = 0; i < dataPoints.length; ++i) {
         if (dataPoints[i] < controlValue) {
             dataPoints[i] = dataPoints[i] * 2;
         }
      }
      
      // This could be combined into the loop above...
      for (i = 0; i < dataPoints.length; ++i) {
         System.out.print(dataPoints[i] + " ");
      }
      System.out.println();
   }
}
```

You could also do all of this in a single loop if you wanted to, for example:

```
for (i = 0; i < dataPoints.length; ++i) {
    dataPoints[i] = scnr.nextInt();

    if (dataPoints[i] < controlValue) {
        dataPoints[i] = dataPoints[i] * 2;
    }

    System.out.print(dataPoints[i] + " ");
}
```